# sed, regex replace with vars

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed (4.2.2-4+b1 debian 8 (jessie)) to replace text in multiple files.

To go from this:

```
$var1 = array(foo=>"bar",bar=>"foo");
$var2 = array( foo=>"bar", bar=>"foo" );
$var1 = array(
    foo=>"bar",
    bar=>"foo"
);
```

To get this:

```
$var1 = array( "foo" => "bar","bar" => "foo");
$var2 = array( "foo" => "bar", "bar" => "foo" );
$var1 = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo"
);
```

The normal regex would be:

```
/(\(|\(\s|,|,\s.+?)([a-z|A-Z].+?)=>/$1"$2" => /g
```

Using sed like this doesn't seem to be working though

```
sed -i "s#\((\|(\s\|,\|,\s.+?\)\([a-zA-z].+?\)=>#\1\"\2\" => #g" *.php
```

Or:

```
sed -i "s#\((\|(\s\|,\|,\s.+?\)\([a-z\|A-z].+?\)=>#\1\"\2\" => #g" *.php
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/([^"])([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)[[:blank:]]*=>/\1"\2" => /g'
```

find a non-quote character, followed by the hash key, followed by optional whitespace followed by `=>`, and insert quotes around the key.

Comment: That didn't work for some reason.

Comment: did you include the `-r` option for sed?

Comment: Yep. `sed -i.bak -r ....`

Comment: Well, "didn't work" is the worst possible problem description. What *did* happen?

Comment: Nothing happened. No error, ran just like when there is a malformed statement.